# If $Q$ is a nonnegative operator on a Hilbert space $U$, show that $\langle Q^{1/2}u_0,Q^{1/2}v_0\rangle_{Q^{1/2}U}=\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_{Q^{1/2}U}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, pseudoinverse

Let

- $U$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $Q\in\mathfrak L(U)$ be nonnegative and self-adjoint
- $Q^{-1/2}$ denote the pseudoinverse of $Q^{1/2}$, i.e. $$Q^{-1/2}:=\left(\left.Q^{1/2}\right|_{\left(\ker Q^{1/2}\right)^\perp}\right)^{-1}$$
- $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$ be equipped with $$\left\langle u_0,v_0\right\rangle_{U_0}:=\left\langle Q^{-1/2}u_0,Q^{-1/2}v_0\right\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for all }u_0,v_0\in U_0$$

> Let $u_0,v_0\in U_0$. I want to show that $$\left\langle Q^{1/2}u_0,Q^{1/2}v_0\right\rangle_{U_0}=\left\langle u_0,v_0\right\rangle_{U_0}.\tag1$$

Let $\operatorname P_{\left(\ker Q^{1/2}\right)^\perp}$ denote the orthogonal projection from $U$ onto $\left(\ker Q^{1/2}\right)^\perp$. Then, $$Q^{-1/2}Q^{1/2}=\operatorname P_{\left(\ker Q^{1/2}\right)^\perp}\tag2$$ and hence (since an orthogonal projection is self-adjoint and idempotent) $$\left\langle Q^{1/2}u_0,Q^{1/2}v_0\right\rangle_{U_0}=\left\langle\operatorname P_{\left(\ker Q^{1/2}\right)^\perp}u_0,v_0\right\rangle_U.\tag3$$

> However, I don't see how this helps to prove $(1)$. So, what can we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equality is not true, even if $Q$ is invertible. For instance take 
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix},\ \ u_0=v_0=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
Q^{1/2}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
You have
$$
\langle Q^{1/2}u_0,Q^{1/2}v_0\rangle_{U_0}=\langle Q^{-1/2}Q^{1/2}u_0,Q^{-1/2}Q^{1/2}v_0\rangle_U=\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_U=1+4=5, 
$$
while
$$
\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_{U_0}=\langle Q^{-1/2}u_0,Q^{-1/2}v_0\rangle_U
=\left\langle \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=2.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. I've read in a book that "by definition", $$\left\langle Q^{1/2}u_0,Q^{1/2}v_0\right\rangle_U=\left\langle u_0,v_0\right\rangle_{U_0}\tag4$$ and thought that the subscript on the left-hand side would be a typo. In fact, with the choices of your example, $$\left\langle Q^{1/2}u_0,Q^{1/2}v_0\right\rangle=\left\langle\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\4\\\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\4\\\end{array}\right)\right\rangle=1+16=17\ne2=\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_{U_0}.$$

Comment: In the book, they use $(4)$ to argue that $$\langle\Phi^\ast x,\Phi^\ast x\rangle_{U_0}=\langle\Phi Q\Phi^\ast x,x\rangle_H\tag5$$ for all Hilbert-Schmidt operators $\Phi$ from $U_0$ to another $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space $H$ and $x\in H$. I'm not able to prove $(5)$. We can show that $$\left\langle Q^{1/2}u_0,v_0\right\rangle_{U_0}=\left\langle u_0,Q^{1/2}v_0\right\rangle_{U_0}$$ and hence $$\left\langle\Phi Q\Phi^\ast x,x\right\rangle_H=\left\langle Q^{1/2}\Phi^\ast x,Q^{1/2}\Phi^\ast x\right\rangle_{U_0}\tag6,$$ but I don't know how we obtain $(5)$ from there. Do you've got an idea?

Comment: Your equality $(5)$ corresponds exactly with the definition $\langle u,v\rangle_{U_0}=\langle Q^{1/2}u,Q^{1/2}v\rangle$. Are you sure it's not like that?

Comment: No, it's not the definition. In the definition, we've got the pseudoinverse of $Q^{1/2}$ and not $Q^{1/2}$ itself. BTW, you can find the proof [here](https://tinyurl.com/y7tqzp95) (Proposition 4.1.7). But I think it's wrong. If we take $\Phi$ to be the $2\times 2$ identity matrix and consider it as a mapping $U_0\to\mathbb R^2$, then we should obtain in your example $\operatorname{tr}\Phi\Phi^\ast=\operatorname{tr}Q$ and $\operatorname{tr}\Phi Q\Phi^\ast=\operatorname{tr}Q^2$.

Comment: In that case, if for example you take $\Phi=Q^{1/2}$, the left-hand-side of $(5)$ is $\langle x,x\rangle$, while the right-hand-side is $\langle Q^2x,x\rangle$.

Comment: The curious thing is that I've found $\operatorname{tr}\Phi\Phi^\ast=\operatorname{tr}\Phi Q\Phi^\ast$ in other books as well ... (it's clear that $\operatorname{tr}\Phi\Phi^\ast=\operatorname{tr}\left(\Phi Q^{1/2}\right)\left(\Phi Q^{1/2}\right)^\ast$.)